# My PHP if else statement work by it self but does not echo

Tags: php

I am trying to do the following with my PHP code, but it doesn't seem to be rendering.

I am not sure if I am doing it right. Can somebody show me where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
    $date1=date_create("2016-05-09 12:00:00"); // due date
    $date2=date_create("2016-05-10 12:00:00");// today date
    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

    $due = ( if ($date1>$date2 or($date1==$date2)) 
             { 
                echo $diff->format("%a        days");
             }
             else 
             {
                echo "its 0";
             });
?>
```

Test case:

```
<?php echo "$due"; ?> // not working
```

Comment: `$due=( if`  no it doesn't. Use the ternary operator. You cannot assign to an if statement.

Comment: Please format your code so it fits without scrolling.

Comment: Where did you read that you can mix variable assignment and `if`/`else` in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
$due = $date1 >= $date2 ? $diff->format("%a days") : 'its 0';
# ---------IF TRUE------^->THEN--------------------^->ELSE.
```

This is called a ternary operator, what you where trying to do is binding syntax to a variable.

What it does is the following:

```
if($date1 >= $date2){
  $due = $diff->format("%a days");
} else {
  $due = 'its 0';
}
```

Comment: The latter is much easier to read and to troubleshoot. I'd be wary of asserting that anything else is "the correct way".

Answer (score 0):

don't use `echo` if you're trying to store a result in a variable. Instead,  use the ternary operator `condition ? value_if_true: value_if_false`

Change:

```
$due=( if ($date1>$date2 or($date1==$date2)) 
            { echo $diff->format("%a days");}
             else {echo "its 0";}
      );
```

To:

```
$due = $date1>=$date2 ? $diff->format("%a days"): "it's 0";
```

[Open the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and scroll down to Ternary Operator for more examples.

Comment: @Kwooly you're welcome. Remember to upvote all the helpful answers if you can, and to select your favorite by clicking the check mark.